# C# WPF Live Charts - Creating a chart generically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF Live Charts Library. I am trying to create a bar chart generically.

Following is my code. Can't do it in XAML as it doesn't support generics.

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericBarChart<T> : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SeriesCollection _SeriesCollection;
    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get { return _SeriesCollection; } set { _SeriesCollection = value; notifyPropertyChanged("SeriesCollection"); } }
    string[] _Labels;
    public string[] Labels { get { return _Labels; } set { _Labels = value; notifyPropertyChanged("Labels"); } }
    Func<int, string> _Formatter;
    public Func<int, string> Formatter { get { return _Formatter; } set { _Formatter = value; notifyPropertyChanged("Formatter"); } }

    public abstract void constructChart(List<T> chartItems);

    public void init(string xLabel, string yLabel)
    {
        renderChart(xLabel, yLabel);
    }

    public void renderChart(string xLabel, string yLabel)
    {
        CartesianChart chart = new CartesianChart { Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10), LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Bottom, DataTooltip = new DefaultTooltip { SelectionMode = TooltipSelectionMode.SharedYValues } };
        Axis xAxis = new Axis { Foreground = Brushes.Black, FontSize = 14d, Title = xLabel };
        Axis yAxis = new Axis { Foreground = Brushes.Black, FontSize = 14d, Title = yLabel };
        chart.AxisX.Add(xAxis);
        chart.AxisY.Add(yAxis);
        setBinding("LabelFormatter", Formatter, xAxis, Axis.LabelFormatterProperty);
        setBinding("Labels", Labels, yAxis, Axis.LabelsProperty);
        setBinding("Series", SeriesCollection, chart, CartesianChart.SeriesProperty);
        Content = chart;
    }

    public void setBinding(string propertyName, object source, FrameworkElement control, DependencyProperty dependencyProperty)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding(propertyName)
        {
            Source = source
        };
        control.SetBinding(dependencyProperty, binding);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void notifyPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}


internal class BarChart : AbstractGenericBarChart<TopTransactingCount>
{
    public override void constructChart(List<TopTransactingCount> chartItems)
    {
        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new RowSeries
            {
                Title = "Transaction Count",
                Values = new ChartValues<long>(chartItems.Select(x=>x.TransCount))
            }
        };
        Labels = chartItems.Select(x => x.Date.ToShortDateString()).ToArray();
        Formatter = value => value.ToString();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

At startup I see an empty chart control which is expected.

I call constructChart method on submit button click.

```
public partial class TotalTransCountsChart : UserControl, IChart
{
    private BarChart chart = new BarChart();
    List<object> chartData;

    public TotalTransCountsChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void init(List<object> chartData)
    {
        this.chartData = chartData;
        chart.init("Transaction Count", "Date");
        chart.constructChart(chartData.Cast<TopTransactingCount>().ToList());
        grid.Children.Add(chart);
        Grid.SetRow(chart, 3);
    }

    private void CmdSubmit_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        chart.constructChart(chartData.Cast<TopTransactingCount>().ToList());
    }
}
```

However, the chart still remains empty. I think the `binding part` in the code is not working as expected. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: If you opt for a Chart Factory, your GenericBarChart Control wouldn't really need to be generic, since the only usage of `T` is with the `constructChart` method. I suggest you refactor the Chart control to be non-generic and then use XAML. However, if your WPF skills allow it, I would rather create a custom `Control` instead of a `UserControl`. For view controls, prefer `DependencyProperty` over `INotifiyPropertyChanged` (INPC). INPC is typically more useful in viewmodel.

Comment: Share full logs please

Answer (score 5):

it looks like you are creating Bindings incorrectly (try to confirm it from Visual Studio Output window - it reports messages about incorrect bindings).

for example:

```
setBinding("Labels", Labels, yAxis, Axis.LabelsProperty);

public void setBinding(string propertyName, object source, FrameworkElement control, DependencyProperty dependencyProperty)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding(propertyName)
    {
        Source = source
    };
    control.SetBinding(dependencyProperty, binding);
}
```

Labels is a `string[]`, and you have a binding , which attempts to use "Labels" property - which doesn't exist.

you need a valid binding source, most likely DataContext:

```
setBinding("LabelFormatter", DataContext, xAxis, Axis.LabelFormatterProperty);
setBinding("Labels", DataContext, yAxis, Axis.LabelsProperty);
setBinding("Series", DataContext, chart, CartesianChart.SeriesProperty);
```

or better yet - don't specify source and all bindings will connect to current DataContext, even if it updates:

```
public void setBinding(string propertyName, object source, FrameworkElement control, DependencyProperty dependencyProperty)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding(propertyName);
    control.SetBinding(dependencyProperty, binding);
}
```